# How can I store, retrieve (and perform munging)large csv files with python.?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, hadoop, nosql

I have a large csv file of size ~ 5-6GB (million of rows). So pandas cannot handle it (it gives memory error as my ram capacity is 2GB). I want to use Hadoop on it (i.e., store block of each file on different nodes) then what are the ways to do it from starting and which Hadoop databases(Hive, HBase, PIG) I use to perform operations on each block. If something is wrong with question then please let me know I am a beginner in this field. 
Or rather than hadoop can I store this huge CSV files in SQL or Postgres if yes then how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can handle large files by reading the file in chunks. If you provide `chunksize` parameter to the `pd.read_csv()` function, a `TextFileReader` will be returned, and you can iterate on it, doing operations on each chuck which fits in memory.

Here is an example which reads 1000 rows at a time and do operation on each chunk:

```
reader = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', chunksize=1000)
for chunk in reader:
    # do operations on chuck which is a dataframe with 1000 rows.
```

Note, the operations you do on each chuck must aggregate or reduce the size of the chuck, and not store them in a list, otherwise you will run out of memory. If you need to do operations on columns so you won't reduce the final size of the `DataFrame`, then after operating on each chuck, store the result in a file.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I don't want to chunk the csv and perform operation on it. I need a solution where I can first move this whole fille data's to database (I had tried SQL but it's took too much of time) and from there I can retrieve a particular set of columns, perform some operations and store the results back to that database. So which database should I use.(Any big data database which works better with python).

Answer (score 0):

You can always read it like a normal text file and parse lines per lines . You can do wahtever treatment on it.

something like:

```
Header = []
with open( 'CSVFile.name' ], 'r') as InputFile:
  for Line in InputFile :
    PureData = re.split( Separator, Line[:-1])
    # assume 1st line is header
    if not Header :
      Header = PureData
    else :
      MyRecord = map( lambda x, y: { x, y }, Header, PureData)

      print( str( MyRecord))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I don't want to split the csv and perform operation on it. I need a solution where I can first move this whole fille data's to database (I had tried SQL but it's took too much of time) and from there I can retrieve a particular set of columns, perform some operations and store the results back to that database. So which database should I use.(Any big data database which works better with python)

Comment: if you dont need to modify the data in the DB, look at something like elasticsearch. It is very efficient in searching from various "point of view", especially on huge DB and tools like logstach will handle your csv 2 ELK finger in the nose.